# Power correct notation

Tags: functions, notation, exponentiation

Ok, I know this may sound dumb, but I am trying to understand which is the correct (most beauty) notation for the power function ${\rm pow}(f(x),n)$.

This is the correct one: $[f(x)]^n$

From trigonometry, where I was used to write $\cos^2x$, we get: $f^n(x)$

And from Bishop's *Pattern Recognition and Machine Learning* I get $\mathbb{E}\,[f(x)^2]$, so: $f(x)^n$

So, is there any other 'me' out there who has already found the correct beauty and elegant way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most *clear* notation is certainly to write $$\left(f(x)\right)^n$$

This is because the notation $f^n(x)$ will frequently refer to the composition $f \circ f \circ ... \circ f$.

Comment: Well, three objections. 1st, don't you switch from ( to [ when you go 'out'? 2nd, is then the $f^n(x)$ notation, with the power acceptation, used specifically for trigonometry? 3rd, I was looking for the prettier one, not for the clearer, but still maintaining correctness.

Comment: @Atcold Regarding the first objection, I (personally) consider it to be 6-of-one, half-dozen of the other. For the second, it's the convention in trigonometry. Third, I don't think that the notation I'm using is particularly not-pretty, and it's certainly clear in all contexts.

Comment: Then I will opt for the $f(x)^2$ (if it's not wrong) in order to reduce overhead and heaviness (I'm making a formulary, so I have to try to do not write a book ^^)

Answer (score 1):

The trigonometry convention is awful and should never be used, but as the other answer indicates it is fine to use that notation for composition, so $f^2(x) = f(f(x))$ which is consistent with using $f^{-1}$ to denote the inverse of $f$.  The extra parentheses are unnecessary, so just write $f(x)^2$, $\cos(x)^2$, etc.  It is also common to omit all the parentheses in some cases, for example $\cos x$ instead of $\cos(x)$, and I wouldn't be surprised to see $\cos{x^2}$ for $\cos(x^2)$.

Comment: Awesome, I really didn't think about the consistency of $f^{-1}$ with $f^n = f \circ f \circ \dots \circ f$. Good point!